# How to print even and odd integers using Numpy arange function

Tags: python, numpy

I am learner , bit stuck not getting how to print odd integers and Even integers using arange function

**For Even :**

```
Print Even integers:
arr = np.arange(5,25,2)
```

The above piece of line does not print even number

**Output :**

```
array([ 5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23])
```

**For Odd**

```
arr = np.arange(5,25,1) 
arr
```

**Output :**

```
array([ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
       22, 23, 24])
```

*Both of them are printing abnormal output*

**This traditional code gives me proper result**

```
start = int(input("Enter the start of range: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end of range: "))
  
# iterating each number in list
for num in range(start, end + 1):
      
    # checking condition
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num, end = " ")
```

How to print even and odd integers using Numpy arange function

Comment: The third argument is a step size, not "2 for even, 1 for odd".

Comment: Just change your start. Both steps have to be `2`

Comment: It's amazing what you learn when you [read the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

Comment: `np.arange(6,24,2)` and `np.arange(5,25,2)` seem to be what you want.  That's "6 to 24 counting by 2s", and "5 to 25 counting by 2s".  Your mental model of the `arange` function is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually assign them to variables and just use an if statement for your code to check if the user wants to print odd elements or even elements.

```
start = 5
end = 25 + 1

# For even
np.arange(start+1, end, 2)

# For odd
np.arange(start, end, 2)
```